# Transformation in Normalizing flow

Tags: generative-models

I'm implementing a Flow based model. The affine transformation for decode (z->x) step is: x_{i} = f(x_{i-1}) = x_{i-1}*exp(s) + t, and for encode step is: x_{i-1} = f_1(x_{i}) = (x_{i} - t)/ exp(s).

My question since the function is bijective, could I use f_1 for decode and f for encode ? I see the affine transformation from z ~ N(0, 1) to x ~ N(mu, var) as the reparameterization trick: x_{i} = x_{i-1}*std + mu

I have tried 2 cases, f_1 for decode gives better result for z ~ N(0, I) to Halfmoon. But I do not know if it is theoretically correct.